# Handling USB cable not connected on linux driver

Tags: c, linux, kernel, usb, driver

**What i need:**
A usb based communiction device from an embedded target (running linux) to a host (running windows)

**What i have:**
A tty-device based on community drivers (u_serial.c, f_acm.c) and a userspace program utilizing the open/close/write/read commands.

**The problem:**
Userspace daemon successfully opens the tty device and reads from it even if the usb cable is not connected. if usb cable is connected while this happens - all usb enumeration is on hold until i cancel the program (cancel the read(), that is).
the same behavior happens when tty is only open()ed, without read().

**What i saw:**
The open() function of my device is defined like the u_serial.c open().
it looks somthing like this:

```
static int gs_open(struct tty_struct *tty, struct file *file)
{
/*
 *definitions
 */

/*
 *basic error checks
 */

//check if the tty device is already open/not opened/currently being opened and deal with each
//if not open:
//<real code starts:>

/* Do the "real open" */
spin_lock_irq(&port->port_lock);

/* allocate circular buffer on first open */
if (port->port_write_buf.buf_buf == NULL) {

    spin_unlock_irq(&port->port_lock);
    status = gs_buf_alloc(&port->port_write_buf, WRITE_BUF_SIZE);
    spin_lock_irq(&port->port_lock);

    if (status) {
        pr_debug("gs_open: ttyGS%d (%p,%p) no buffer\n",
            port->port_num, tty, file);
        port->openclose = false;
        goto exit_unlock_port;
    }
}


tty->driver_data = port;
port->port_tty = tty;

port->open_count = 1;
port->openclose = false;


/* if connected, start the I/O stream */
if (port->port_usb) {
    struct gserial  *gser = port->port_usb;

    pr_debug("gs_open: start ttyGS%d\n", port->port_num);
    gs_start_io(port);

    if (gser->connect)
        gser->connect(gser);
}

pr_debug("gs_open: ttyGS%d (%p,%p)\n", port->port_num, tty, file);

status = 0;

exit_unlock_port:
spin_unlock_irq(&port->port_lock);
return status;
}
```

Some not related code was removed. see source [here](https://github.com/gp-b2g/gp-peak-kernel/blob/master/drivers/usb/gadget/u_serial.c).

Note that even if usb is not connected (port->port_usb is 0) - we continue and return 0, which means everything is ok.
also note that if usb is not connected, we do not execute gs_start_io(), which is used to do the actual read from device, and works only if usb is connected.

So one question here is - if the kernel is built with no errors on open() command while usb cable is not connected - why is it holding when i have an open descriptor to the device?
i would assume that either it would fail to open the device in the first place, or ignore the situation and continue the usb connection normally.
also, if this is the correct behavior - how can i deal with/know if the cable is disconnected?

A similar discussion was held [here](http://davinci-linux-open-source.linux.davincidsp.com.narkive.com/6cSs8jnw/usb-serial-gadget-potential-bug-in-driver) some years ago, with no real conlclusions..

And a final thought - the issue can be dealt with if the userspace program will be notified when usb is connected, but this doesn't mean the current behavior is right.

thanks.